# How do I turn an Apache Cordova App into a Web Application?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, apache-cordova

I'm building an Application on Apache Cordova Visual studio platform, and I want to target mobile devices, which Apache-Cordova is great at. But I also want to be able to provide a solution that can be hosted on IIS and deliver a web experience.

Is this possible? I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, So the short answer is you can't through Apache-Cordova, at least from what I can tell.

However, if you take all the necessary html, css, and js files, from your project. You can create an old fashioned www folder and host that on IIS.https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350(v=ws.10).aspx